# UINavigationController inside UITabBarController - Change UITabBar background color

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, setbackground

I have a problem changing the background color of my `UITabBar`. I have a `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` inside one with a root view.

Tab Bar Controller > Navigation Controller > Root View

[image]

In `UITabBarController` class I have the following code:

```
[self.UITabBarHome setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

The color applies in my `UITabBar` until I click the `UITabBarItem` (Group) that directs to my `UINavigationController`. When I click this item only, the color changes to the default color.How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a UITabBar in the root view controller of the UINavigationController

Comment: A `UITabBar` inside a navigation controller? Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: My initial view controller is a tabBarController with three views and a navigationController with three views. I added the tabbar to solve the problem of background, maybe I explained wrong. 

It's like this example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can target every instance of a UITabBar in your app:

`[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Other properties:

`UIColor *tintColor; 
 UIColor *selectedImageTintColor;
 UIImage *backgroundImage;
 UIImage *selectionIndicatorImage;`

Comment: The same thing happens. I had tried to set the color in appDelegate. It's like UINavitagionController "instantiates" a new UITabBar, but with the same items.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewController.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .red
```

Note-> `viewController` is an instance of your ViewController